# Changing Image Button with a Gallery Image in Android

Tags: java, android, image, imagebutton, android-imagebutton

I have looked around for a solution to the below problem I am having, and have not found anything.
In the app, I have an ImageButton with a predefined drawable. What I was is the ability for the user to click on this ImageButton, pick a picture from the Phone's image Gallery and show that picture until the user changes it again.
So far I manage to get the ImageGallery to show and able to pick a picture, but I am not able to do the following:

```
1. Show the Picture from the Picture Gallery in the shape of the original drawable -- it is a circle
2. When I change activity and come back to this activity, the picture chosen is not there anymore.
```

My Code looks like this:
XML for the ImageButton is within a LinearLayout

```
        <ImageButton 
            android:id="@+id/AddPic"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="0.4"
            android:background="#00FFFFFF"
            android:contentDescription="@string/MyInformation"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:onClick="AddPic"
            android:src="@drawable/dp_holder_large" 
            />
```

My Java Code look like this:

```
    public class MyInformation extends Activity{

    ImageButton imgButton;   
    public static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;

   @Override  
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.myinformation);


        //Adding the picture bit   

        imgButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.AddPic);
        imgButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent GaleryIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                startActivityForResult(GaleryIntent, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
            Uri SelectedImage = data.getData();
            String[] FilePathColumn = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

            Cursor SelectedCursor = getContentResolver().query(SelectedImage, FilePathColumn, null, null, null);
            SelectedCursor.moveToFirst();

            int columnIndex = SelectedCursor.getColumnIndex(FilePathColumn[0]);
            String picturePath = SelectedCursor.getString(columnIndex);
            SelectedCursor.close();

          //  Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(getResources(),BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath)); 
           // btnOpenGalery .setImageBitmap(d);
            imgButton.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), picturePath, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

    }   

     @Override
     public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
         // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
         getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
         return true;
     }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Can solve your second problem. But couldn't understand what you mean in 1st problem?

Comment: Ah! Ok, apologies it was not clear. The drawable shown until the user picks a picture is a black circle. I want the picture the user selects to "fit" within this circle ... does that explain it better? Thanks

Comment: Please refer to my answer below and let me know if you have any problem. Good luck

Answer (score 0):

**Solution for problem 1:**

Remove the background and make a custom background with circle.

Don't use `android:src="@drawable/dp_holder_large"`

Because once you set image to it, then the circle will vanish

**Solution for problem 2:**

You need to call new activities with `startActivityForResult()` method

```
Intent newIntent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NextActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(newIntent, 2);
```

And in your `onActivityResult()` method do

```
if(resultCode==2){
imgButton.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));//where picturePath is the path
}
```

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. I took out the android:src line and used as background a custom circle. Unfortunately it made no difference as the image picked appeared as a rectangle. On the solution for problem 2, I am not sure what to do ...

Comment: thanks for the updated code. The issue is not that I am not able to select the picture. I can select the picture and it appears in the image button, BUT it does not save, so the image does not appear if I close the app or I move to a new activity and come back. I thought I could save the path of the image in SharedPreferences and so invoke it when the activity is called, but I don't know how to do this with an image button. Does this explain better? Thanks again.

Comment: So if I help you save **picturePath** in SharedPreference and retrieve back when needed, you will be able to solve your problem?

Comment: Hi, I actually solved the first issue myself, which I was pleased about as I am quite new at this. I read that it was best to store the path in shared preferences and then retrieve the path. This line of code made sure that I retrieved the path: 'File imgFile = new File(sharedpreferences.getString(Path, LOCATION_SERVICE));'